# Using custom shortcut keys in ArcGIS while table of attributes is active window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

I have a custom button which is made using python add-in.

I add this button in arcgis desktop and assign a new short-cut key for this button.

The problem is this button should be used while table of attributes is active.
But short-cut key only works when main acrmap window is active.

Is there any way to assign short-cut keys for custom buttons and make them work while table of attributes is active?

Answer (score 2):

I've not had to create a Python AddIn but looking at the help file it seems that a button can only be placed on a tool bar, you cannot place it on the table window "tool bar". Based upon that it does not surprise me that the shortcut key only executes on the main map window. [These](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s00000006000000) are the Table short-cuts and it does say the table window must have focus, by clicking on your addIn button on a tool bar you are moving focus away from the table window...

Comment: Looks like it's imposible to solve this problem using only standart ArcGIS functionality. Maybe there are other ways out?

Comment: You get more control with ArcObjects, there are events that you can listen for and activate/deactivate the tool accordingly or simply return(); if a specific condition isn't met.